# Cannot clear an interval after opening a modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, intervals

I am trying to create and clear an interval depending on if the modal is open or closed. I can get it to run, but as soon as I close the modal, it shows an error:

> var myInterval is not defined

`myInterval` is defined, though. What am I doing wrong?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#modal-task").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
    // This works
    var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
      startTask();
    }, 3000);
  });

  $('#modal-task').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
    // This throws the error: var myInterval is not defined
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    console.log("Hide Modal. Clear Interval");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you only declare  `myInterval` within scope of the `shown.bs.modal` handler. For it to be accessible by both functions you need to declare it at the lowest possible scope accessible in both locations. In this case, that would be in the document.ready handler:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var myInterval;

  $("#modal-task").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
    myInterval = setInterval(function() {
      startTask();
    }, 3000);
  });

  $('#modal-task').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    console.log("Hide Modal. Clear Interval");
  });
});
```